# Is it possible to get the read() function to retrieve hexa bytes values from a file?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand some piece of code, and I would like to know if it can actually work.

I don't know the content of file "test", but I imagine it must match with the "cases" you can see in the code.

I have tried this code by creating a file "test" with content "\x08" or "0x08" (or \x04 and 0x04) but it does not go into the 2 first cases (instead the read function take "\", then "x" then "0" etc. then put it in variable `i`)

```
int main(){

    int i;

    fd = open("test",O_RDONLY);

    read(fd,&i,1);
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0x08:
           printf("0x08");
           break;
        case 0x04:
           printf("0x04");
           break;
        case 0x61:
           printf("0x61");
           break;
        default:
           printf("default\n"); 
     }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

For case 3 (0x61), it works when I put char `a` in the file (because `a`'s hexa value is `0x61`), but what can I put in the file for the 2 first cases ?

Thank you

Comment: the size of an `int` is not 1 try with a `char` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Stargateur so there is no way to go into the 1st two cases ? (this is not my code, I just want to check if it's valid or not)

Comment: `"\x08"` is not the same as `\x08`. The former is an array of four numbers: `0x5C`, `0x78`, `0x30`, and `0x38`. The latter is one number `0x08`.

Comment: Please have a look at `strtol`. It converts a string in any number base to `long`. But it won't like the `0x` prefix.

Comment: always check (>0) the returned value from `open()` to assure the operation was successful.   always check the returned value from `read()` to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: from the question, it seems that the file `test` is an ascii/text file.  If so, then `0x04` would be 4 characters, not 1.  Suggest using something like `scanf()` to input/convert the text into an `int` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own test file generator:

```
...
int i; /* or char i; */
d = open("test", O_WRONLY);
i = 8;
write(fd, &i, sizeof(int)); /* or 1 */
i = 4;
write(fd, &i, sizeof(int)); /* or 1 */
i = 0x61;
write(fd, &i, sizeof(int)); /* or 1 */
close(d);
....
```

Comment: this has the problem of writing a binary file, rather than a text file.  That may help with the reading of the file contents into a 'int' variable using the `read()` statement.   However, the file will not be printable nor human readable

Comment: A human readable file cannot have characters 0x08 and 0x04 and would be useless for testing.